# Weblogic Server memory and swap space is not getting free

Tags: java, memory, weblogic, oracle-adf

I have developed a Fusion Web Application on Oracle ADF.

Now i have deployed this Application on Weblogic Linux 64bit server and test this application using JMeter.

Initially i have test this application with 50 users then 100 and 500 users.

**Problem is this, Server Memory and Swap space is not getting free.**

It is getting increase even i run the 10 users test multiple times

Comment: Have you tested increasing JVM memory space?

Comment: I have increase the JVM memory usage upto 6GB. but now it is not getting low.

Comment: Which JVM you are using for your container? I think JRocket best suits weblogic, and It comes with its own memory management algorithms.

Comment: I strongly believe you have a memory leak! Check the GC logs and confirm if you are getting any Out of Memory errors.

Comment: Now i am using JRockit for this deployment. Still problem is there. If there is some memory leakage issue then how to overcome this issue. I have developed a small Application with only login and logout scenario and test with jMeter each time server memory getting higher. It is not getting reduce even I have stopped the test